# Weka multilayer perceptron classifier output to code

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, weka

I am newbie in using weka and neural networks. I am little confused in transforming weka output to the code level.
Here it is my weka output for the trained multilayer perceptron.

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Sigmoid Node 0
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -7.728242643484787
    Node 2    9.643254844595948
    Node 3    -8.919025399127651
Sigmoid Node 1
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    7.728242205764689
    Node 2    -9.643254376294452
    Node 3    8.91902493707197
Sigmoid Node 2
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    21.0918376938558
    Attrib mean    -19.54425890349859
    Attrib std    36.730369650588976
Sigmoid Node 3
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    16.25280971170097
    Attrib mean    -17.677516091162413
    Attrib std    14.141388386397688
Class valid
    Input
    Node 0
Class invalid
    Input
    Node 1
```

and here it is how I am converting to MATLAB code

```
node3 = sdev * 14.141388386397688 +  avg *-17.677516091162413;
node3 = 1 / (1 + exp(-node3));
if(node3 < 16.25280971170097)
    node3 = 0;
end

node2 = sdev * 36.730369650588976 +  avg * -19.54425890349859;
node2 = 1 / (1 + exp(-node2));
if(node2 < 21.0918376938558)
    node2 = 0;
end

node1 = node3 * 8.91902493707197 +  node2 * -9.643254376294452;
node1 = 1 / (1 + exp(-node1));
if(node1 < 7.728242205764689)
    node1 = 0;
end

node0 = node3 * -8.91902493707197 +  node2 * 9.643254376294452;
node0 = 1 / (1 + exp(-node0));
if(node0 < -7.728242205764689)
    node0 = 0;
end
```

But I am getting some weird output using this, can anybody please help me in transforming the weka generated output to functional neural network.

Comment: That's not how thresholds work in a multilayer network; you add them into a node's input *before* computing the logistic sigmoid. Pick up any good book on neural networks for the formulas.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, is this what do you mean  node0 = node3 * -8.91902493707197 +  node2 * 9.643254376294452 -7.728242205764689;
node0 = 1 / (1 + exp(-node0)); then how can I use node0 output for classification?

Comment: That might be it, or you might have to add `7.728` -- it depends on Weka conventions, which I'm not familiar with. How to do classification depends on the structure of the network, which is not apparent from the question.

Answer (score -1):

What you currently have from Weka is a network itself (its weights and attributes). AFAIK, Weka can generate Java source code for classifiers, listed on [this page](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html). I'm not sure your classifier is one of these classes. If it does support this, then just choose `Classify` -> `More options` -> `Output source code`. Here is some [explanation from Weka mailing list](https://list.scms.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2011-June/052649.html).

Comment: MLP hasn't implemented `Sourcable` interface so it can't generate the classifier source code. ([Here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html) is document of MLP class.)